# Set HandleShow of a Modal from another script

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, reactjs, modal, google-chart-api

quiero mostrar un modal dependiendo el estado que clicke en mi mapa de google charts, estoy intentando mandar el handleshow desde charts event, para que cuando le clicke ejecute el show y se muestre el id

```
const chartEvents=[{
      eventName: "ready", 
      callback: ({ chartWrapper, google }) => {
        const chart = chartWrapper.getChart();
        google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, "select", e => {
          
          if(chart.getSelection()[0].row === 0){
         
        });
      }
    }
```

My Modal Component:

```
function HandleModal() {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  
    const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
    const handleShow = () => setShow(true);
    
    return (
      <>
        <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleShow}>
          Launch demo modal
        </Button>
  
        <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal!</Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
              Close
            </Button>
            <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
              Save Changes
            </Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
      </>
    );
  }
  export default HandleModal
```

Entonces como accedo a handleshow desde otro script para ejecutar el modal?

Comment: Bienvenido a SO Español, por favor traduce tu pregunta o acabara siendo cerrada.

Answer (score 0):

No se cual es la estructura de componentes, pero si es padre/hijo, es decir en el componente donde se define `chartEvents`, es donde se renderiza `<HandleModal />` le podrías pasar un parametro a HandleModal para controlar si se tiene que mostrar o no, y con un useState controlarlo desde el padre:

```
const[showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

<HandleModal show={showModal} />
```

Y dentro del componente hacer que se muestre o no en función de lo que le llega en la propiedad.

Entonces dentro del `chartEvents` deberías hacer un `setShowModal(true)` para que se muestre.